# HDFS Storage Policies Change，but file size does not change

Tags: hdfs, storage, policy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzjNT.jpg)

When I change the file storage policy from hot to cold, the file size should be smaller because the archive type has a higher storage density, but there is no change so far

Answer (score 0):

Changing storage type won’t change the filesize, the filesize is determined by the content of the file.
Changing the Storage Policy from HOT to COLD will just make sure the blocks of data corresponding to that file moves from DISK to ARCHIVAL storage. No change in size will happen, just the storage type of blocks changes